# Node.js Express Server on Forwarded Localhost - Not Responding

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs

I'm new to Node.js. Started following [Sahat Yalkabov's](http://sahatyalkabov.com/create-a-character-voting-app-using-react-nodejs-mongodb-and-socketio/) tutorial on creating a Node.js Express + React.js app.

I connected to my server with SSH (PUTTY) and forwarded port 3000 to `localhost:3000`. However, when I try to connect to the server with my browser it doesn't respond and the browser just shows `waiting for localhost` message.

I have previously ran `express` command and their default project did show on my browser, so it's not a firewall thing.

Here is `server.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Server-side React rendering
var swig  = require('swig');
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom/server');
var Router = require('react-router');
var RoutingContext = Router.RoutingContext;
var routes = require('./app/routes');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Server-side React rendering
app.use(function(req, res) {
  Router.match({ routes: routes, location: req.url }, function(err, redirectLocation, renderProps) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(500, err.message)
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
      res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
    } else if (renderProps) {
      var html = ReactDOM.renderToString(<RoutingContext {...renderProps} />);
      var page = swig.renderFile('views/index.html', { html: html });
      res.send(200, page);
    } else {
      res.send(404, 'Page Not Found')
    }
  });
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

To run the server, I'm using 2 terminals, one running `gulp` and the other `npm run watch`, as per said tutorial.

I'm really new to all of this, first time running Node.js.
Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT: Added a git repository with my project, [here](https://github.com/Neta-Alon/First-Express-React.js-Server).**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should only run `npm run watch` command.
After terminal shows `Express server listening on port 3000`,
please open `http://localhost:3000/` on your browser.